# Partysip Installation

Tags: parsing, session, udp, sdp

I can not install the partysip by following the [instructions](http://www.nongnu.org/partysip/FAQ-partysip.html). It seems path missing of oSip and oSipParser. Could anybody tell me how can I install Partysip using oSip? Here is following message:

```
./ppl/ppl_uinfo.h:28:37: error: osipparser2/osip_parser.h: No such file or directory
./ppl/ppl_uinfo.h:29:27: error: osip2/osip_mt.h: No such file or directory
In file included from pplinit.c:23:
./ppl/ppl_uinfo.h:55: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'osip_uri_t'
./ppl/ppl_uinfo.h:58: warning: struct has no members
./ppl/ppl_uinfo.h:64: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'osip_contact_t'
./ppl/ppl_uinfo.h:70: warning: struct has no members
./ppl/ppl_uinfo.h:107: error: expected ')' before '*' token
./ppl/ppl_uinfo.h:117: error: expected ')' before '*' token
./ppl/ppl_uinfo.h:146: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'osip_contact_t'
./ppl/ppl_uinfo.h:153: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'osip_contact_t'
./ppl/ppl_uinfo.h:160: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'osip_uri_t'
make[4]: *** [pplinit.lo] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/partysip-2.2.3/ppl/unix'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/partysip-2.2.3/ppl/unix'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/partysip-2.2.3/ppl'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/partysip-2.2.3'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Install libosip http://www.gnu.org/software/osip/ (version 2.2.0) first and then, use the following additionnal CFLAGS to compile partysip:

```
CFLAGS="-lresolv -losipparser2" ./configure
```